# reload collection view with Animation

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, uicollectionview

I want to reload collection with animation. I gone through documentation, they have provided below method. I used it. It is working fine. Now I want to handle speed of animation (slow/fast). Is it possible through this method?

```
  - (void)performBatchUpdates:(void (^)(void))updates completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

My code:

```
[mycollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [mycollectionView reloadData];
   };
```

Answer (score 2):

to add moving effect and animation to cells :

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

    CGFloat xx=cell.frame.origin.x;
         CGFloat yy=cell.frame.origin.y;



        CGRect frame = cell.frame;
        frame.origin.x = 500; // new x coordinate
        frame.origin.y = 0; // new y coordinate
        cell.frame = frame;


        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{

            CGRect frame = cell.frame;
            frame.origin.x = xx; // new x coordinate
            frame.origin.y = yy; // new y coordinate
            cell.frame = frame;
            // cell.entityImageEffect.alpha = 1;
        }];

    return cell;

    }
```

Comment: I added this, but when scrolling the view, the cells are animated each time since the reusable cell is created everytime it is shown..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I don't think it is really possible to do via simply calling `performBatchUpdates:`, I don't think It makes sense overriding it.

But simple trick to do this is to make a cell transparent, and then call a UIView's `animateWithDuration:animations:` in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`

For example:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SMSourceEntityCell";
    SMSourceEntityCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundImageView.alpha = 0.1;
    cell.entityImageView.alpha = 0.1;
    cell.entityImageEffect.alpha = 0.1;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        cell.backgroundImageView.alpha = 1;
        cell.entityImageView.alpha = 1;
        cell.entityImageEffect.alpha = 1;
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whew. I'm a bit late, but if you're caching the contents of your cell, you can just animate the items that aren't cached yet and let the cached cells display as is. That way you aren't repeating cell animation for the cells that are reused.